# iTextSharp Vertical Spacing

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to generate some PDF files. I have two tables which have content, and I want to put some space between the two tables, say the equivalent of 1 line of text (using the same font as the tables around the space).

Below is the code I'm using to add the two tables. What I cannot figure out is how to place a vertical space between the two tables.

```
Table upperTable = new Table(1);
upperTable.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
upperTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
upperTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
upperTable.AddCell(new Phrase("some text", font3));
d.Add(upperTable);
Table lowerTable= new Table(1);
lowerTable.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
lowerTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
lowerTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
lowerTable.AddCell(new Phrase("some other text", font3));
d.Add(lowerTable);
```

Can someone tell me how I can add the vertical space between the two tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that sort of works... add the new lines as part of either the preceding string, or the following string to the space that I want to create. For example:

```
Table upperTable = new Table(1);
upperTable.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
upperTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
upperTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
upperTable.AddCell(new Phrase("some text" + '\n', font3));
d.Add(upperTable);
Table lowerTable= new Table(1);
lowerTable.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
lowerTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
lowerTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
lowerTable.AddCell(new Phrase('\n' + "some other text", font3));
d.Add(lowerTable);
```

would cause 2 lines whose height is defined by `font3` to be added between the `"some text"` and `"some other text"`

Answer (score 14):

Use PdfPTable instead. It has properties `SpacingBefore` and `SpacingAfter`

For example:

```
PdfPTable upperTable = new PdfPTable(1);
upperTable.AddCell(new Phrase("some text", font3));
upperTable.SpacingAfter = 10f;
```

Comment: The question was of 2009. iTextSharp had the `Table` object until 4.3.x , and from version 5.x on, it is `PdfPTable`